# Как ожидать результат выполнения асинхронного кода?

Tags: c#, asp.net, асинхронность

Есть такой клас

```
static public class Methods
{
    static Customer[] customers;

    public static Customer[] GetCustomers(string login, string password)
    {
        AtmisOrderServiceSoapClient client = new AtmisOrderServiceSoapClient();
        login = "login";
        password = "password";
        client.GetCustomersAsync(new GetCustomersRequest(login, password));
        client.GetCustomersCompleted += Client_GetCustomersCompleted;
        return customers;
    }


    static void Client_GetCustomersCompleted(object sender, GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       customers = e.Result.GetCustomersResult.Customers;
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь достать кастомеров:

```
 private void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Customer[] customers= Methods.GetCustomers("", "");
        //   Services.SynlabServices.Customer[] customers = Methods.GetCustomers(login,password);

    }
```

Как заставить метод LogIn ожидать получения всех кастомеров?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По тому коду, который вы предоставили, у вас имеется асинхронная модель, основанная на событиях.

Для ожидания получения результатов асинхронного вызова, можно создать [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)(при помощи [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)), который будет возвращать нам массив кастомеров. Задача будет выполнена только тогда, когда сработает событие `Client_GetCustomersCompleted`.

Реализация будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
static public class Methods
{
    static TaskCompletionSource<Customer[]> tcs;

    public static Task<Customer[]> GetCustomersAsync(string login, string password)
    {
        AtmisOrderServiceSoapClient client = new AtmisOrderServiceSoapClient();
        login = "login";
        password = "password";
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Customer[]>(); 
        try
        {    
           client.GetCustomersAsync(new GetCustomersRequest(login, password));
           client.GetCustomersCompleted += Client_GetCustomersCompleted;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
             tcs.setException(ex);
        }
        return tcs.Task;
    }


    static void Client_GetCustomersCompleted(object sender, GetCustomersCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       tcs.setResult(e.Result.GetCustomersResult.Customers);
    }
}


private void LogIn(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Customer[] customers= Methods.GetCustomers("", "").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //   Services.SynlabServices.Customer[] customers = Methods.GetCustomers(login,password);

    }
```

Дополнительно ознакомьтесь с рекомендациями по [реализации асинхронной модели](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/best-practices-for-implementing-the-event-based-asynchronous-pattern) на базе событий. 
 Особое внимание стоит обратить на обработку исключений и ошибок в ходе выполнения асинхронной операции. Касательно к предложенной реализации, если произойдет исключение(или ошибка), задача никогда не завершится. Вы должны расширить код, чтобы обрабатывать корректно ошибки и исключение в ходе выполнения асинхронной операции.